# How to pass many input of HTML data into javascript without sending too many id at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a random questions on how to pass my html data which contains many type of input. I will provide a picture how my application looks like that needs to send many input to javascript in order to be processed there.

First here is there picture:

[image: Screenshot]

Now inside my html, i have prepare jsfiddle for it. [JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/n5hxs1w4/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id="registerform">
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <p><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<u>1st Subject</u></b></p>
            <table id="tableAdd" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Subject</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</td>
            <td>
            <div class="list">
                <select id="subjek'+id+'">
                <option selected>Select subject</option>
                <option>-----Major Subject-----</option>
                <option>PHP</option>
                <option>Final Year Project</option>
                <option>-----Elective Subject-----</option>
                <option>Computer Animation</option>
                <option>-----Uni Subject-----</option>
                <option>Mathematics</option>
                <option>Beginner Calculus</option>
                <option>Titas</option>
                <option>Hubungan Etnik</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Date (From)</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :</td>
            <td><br>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Date (To)</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :</td>
            <td><br>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker2">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Time (From)</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :</td>
            <td><br>
            <input type="text" id="timepicker">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <td><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Time (To)</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :</td>
            <td><br>
            <input type="text" id="timepicker2">
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
    </div>
```

As you can you see on provided jsfiddle, i have so much input on that particular block of code. When you see the picture given, noticed that i have 11 tab which is from `1st Subject` to`11th Subject` and all of them contain same type of form. Let's assume if the user want to fill the form until `11th Subject`, is there any recommended method to pass all the data to javascript?

p/s: i am hoping for an easy method to pass HTML data without troubling me with bugs because there are so many data to be passed into javascript.

Comment: _"pass all the data to javascript"_ ?What do you mean ?

Comment: it means pass all the input data from the form to javascript. I would prefer send by id but i'm not sure how to do that with so many input in one form. Also in there's 11 tab which contain same form that i want to send the input data to javascript

Comment: How about `$(FORM_SELECTOR).serialize()` ?

Comment: to use serialize you will need to add name attributes to input and select elements.

Comment: so there's no need to use id then? when i use this serialize, can i call any input inside the form? sorry i'm kinda weak with jquery

Comment: I have a questions. Assuming i use this serialize method.  If i have 11 tab. Then i need to name every 11 form?

Comment: Or `$('formID').find(":input").each(function() {});`